# enums declaration in struct

Tags: c++, c

[Horde3d](http://www.horde3d.org/) claims a C 'style' interface available. But I'm unable to include the headers compiling a C source, because of these errors:

```
..../../horde3d/SDK_1.0.0_Beta5/Horde3D/Bindings/C++/Horde3D.h:127: error: nested redefinition of ‘enum List’
```

due to these declarations:

```
....

struct H3DOptions
{
    /* ... */
    enum List
    {
        MaxLogLevel = 1,
        MaxNumMessages,
        TrilinearFiltering,
        ....
    };
...
};

struct H3DStats
{
    /* ... */
    enum List
    {
        TriCount = 100,
        BatchCount,
        LightPassCount,
        ...
    };
};
```

....

Being Horde3d really developed in C++, the identifier List get qualified by enclosing struct. This seem not available in C. Does exists some workaround, apart rewriting the headers?

Comment: Do they claim to have "C bindings", or just  a "C-style interface"?

Comment: Rewrite the header, don't include the problematic header or use a C++ compiler seem to be your only options

Comment: @awoodland: I agree, considering that the header also *uses* these definitions - and `::` is not valid C...

Comment: Thanks all. I'll rewrite the header(s).

Answer (score 3):

It was done on purpose. Appendix C of the C++ standard explains:

> **Change:** A struct is a scope in C++, not in C
>   **Rationale:** Class scope is crucial to C++, and a struct is a class.
>   **Effect on original feature:** Change to semantics of well-defined feature.
>   **Difficulty of converting:** Semantic transformation.
>   **How widely used:** C programs use struct extremely frequently, but the change is only noticeable when struct, enumeration, or enumerator names are referred to outside the struct. The latter is probably rare.

Obviously the committee only considered how valid C code would work as C++, not if C++ code using the new features would still be valid C.

Comment: I don't see, how this answers the question and how this could help chac with his problem.

Comment: It explains why it doesn't work - the "C interface" is using C++ scoping rules so it cannot be compiled as C. In C++ the enums are local to each struct, in C they are not.

Comment: @Bo Persson: because I found myself a solution, I have to unselect your answer, that previously I accepted, to be able to accept my answer. Hope this don't hurts...

Comment: @chac - Sure, you are supposed to select the answer that works the best for *you*, and that might change over time. Not the first time this happens to me either, and I still have some reps left.

Answer (score 2):

In C, in a single translation unit all `enum` tag names live in the same name space, you cannot reuse them twice. You have to change your second `enum` tag if you want both of them to coexist.

Answer (score 1):

I (almost) found the solution I was looking for: a set of macros that placed before the include allows interfacing Horde3D in C.

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#define TOKPASTE1(x, y) x ## y
#define TOKPASTE2(x, y) TOKPASTE1(x, y)

/* List is shared between many structs
 */
#define List TOKPASTE2(List_, __LINE__)

/* these symbols are duplicated: their functionality is compromised
 */
#define Code TOKPASTE2(Code_, __LINE__)
#define SamplerElem TOKPASTE2(SamplerElem_, __LINE__)
#define UniformElem TOKPASTE2(UniformElem_, __LINE__)
#define SampNameStr TOKPASTE2(SampNameStr_, __LINE__)
#define UnifNameStr TOKPASTE2(UnifNameStr_, __LINE__)
#define Undefined   TOKPASTE2(Undefined_,   __LINE__)
#define MatResI     TOKPASTE2(MatResI_,     __LINE__)

#include <Horde3D.h>
#include <Horde3DUtils.h>

/* disambiguate C client code:
   let the compiler signal eventual usage of compromised symbols
 */
#undef List
#undef Code
#undef SamplerElem
#undef UniformElem
#undef SampNameStr
#undef UnifNameStr
#undef Undefined
#undef MatResI
```

**edit**

As Christoph pointed out, it's *use* of non C tokens that inhibits a full solution. These macros above leave just 3 errors due to H3DOptions::List and H3DStats::List usage. I've then edited the Horde3D.h, and added

```
#define H3DStats__List int
#define H3DOptions__List int
```

to the macros above. Compiling in C++ with now would require

```
#define H3DStats__List H3DStats::List
#define H3DOptions__List H3DOptions::List
```